# Show the differences in two test-coverage runs

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm in the process of writing tests for some old and disowned code. I've found coverage.py to be a useful tool in helping me decide which test to write next. As I improve our testing I'd like to see how I've affected our coverage.

Currently I'm doing this by bringing up the html report twice, in side-by-side browser windows, and visually looking for differences. This seems very crude. Do any of you have a better solution?

I found [z3c.coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.coverage#using-coveragediff), and after struggling to get zope-testrunner working with our tests, found that it only reports on regressions, not improvements. I could give the inputs as reverse, so that improvements look like regressions, but that will be quite confusing to present to others.

Answer (score 2):

Coverage.py doesn't have a diff feature.  Sounds cool though, want to provide a patch? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was in similar situation. I wanted to see if the coverage has dropped. 
There was no straight forward way to get it.
so, I wrote some python script and a shell script. I works fine, I have it jenkins now.

**Steps**

1. Store previous report and current report (something report.prev and report.curr)

report text format:(this is default format and found it easy to parse)

```
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
my/project/example.py                     3      3     0%
```

2. parse report into maps
   where key, value is { filename : coverage_percentage }

   **example:**

> ```
> previous_run = { 
>     '/my/filename.py' : '67', 
>     '/one/more/file.py' : '89'
> }
>
> current_run = {
>     '/my/filename.py' : '67',
>     '/one/more/file.py' : '89'
> }
> ```

3. Then we can compare these maps (current_run, previous_run)
4. On new report generation, roll the files: Meaning, move current report file to previous ('mv report.curr report.prev') and new file to report.curr

I have put full implementation here:
https://github.com/diganthdr/handytools
See (coverage_compare.py)