# Incremental code coverage for Python unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-unittest, coverage.py

How can I get an **incremental** report on code coverage in Python?

By "incremental", I mean what has been the change in the covered lines since some "last" report, or from a particular Git commit.

I'm using `unittest` and `coverage` (and coveralls.io) to get the code coverage statistics, which work great. But I'm involved only with a part of the project, and at first I'm concerned with what **my last commit** has changed. I expected `coverage` to be able to show the difference between two reports, but so far have not found anything short of running textual diff on HTML output.

Comment: I suspect this will get closed as asking for a recommendation for software. Likely this will be a feature of your CI (unittest and coverage don't understand git and for good reason). You may look at [codeclimate](https://codeclimate.com/), which IIRC does this (free for open source as well).

Comment: @BaileyParker Thank you for the note. I do not necessarily require integration with Git (although that would be nice), the difference from a "previous run" would be fine too. I expected `coverage` to be able to show the difference between two runs, but so far have not found anything short of running textual diff on HTML output. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yes I just assumed since you were using coveralls.io that you were using version control. For diffing two runs, (you'd need to do some legwork), but `coverage xml` can output an xml report which you may be able to parse yourself and then diff (it may also provide utilities to parse the XML for you).

Comment: Diff cover is the tool
https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff-cover

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Brief**

I use [pycobertura](https://github.com/aconrad/pycobertura).

`pycobertura diff --format html --output cov_diff.html coverage_old.xml coverage_new.xml`

---

**Details**

I use the following chain ([coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io)):

1. Generate coverage report:
   `python -m coverage run -m unittest`
2. Output cobertura's XML format:
   `coverage xml --omit tests/* -o cover_old.xml`
3. -- Modify code or checkout newer commit --
4. Generate coverage report:
   `python -m coverage run -m unittest`
5. Output cobertura's XML format:
   `coverage xml --omit tests/* -o cover_new.xml`
6. Generate diff: `pycobertura diff --format html --output cov_diff.html coverage_old.xml coverage_new.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer to similar question, it might help. Compares previous run and current run.

[show-the-differences-in-two-test-coverage-runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212589/10455094)