# python test coverage comparison with previous run

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py, test-coverage

I am using [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io) to check the code coverage of my unit tests, in form of html report.

```
coverage run -m pytest
coverage html
```

The report is pretty cool which shows the overall coverage % and the coverage % of individual .py file. Every time I finished some code changes I would re-run the coverage report to check if my unit test test cases can cover the new codes well. However, the issue is that I have to spot manually if any .py file has particularly low coverage.

Is there any way or existing tool I can use to compare the test coverage with previous/historical run? So that I can easily spot if any .py file has significantly dropped coverage.

Comment: Checkouot [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58838709/2506522) to a similar question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is not supported by coverage.py currently, but can be built outside of coverage.py

**codecov.io**

Services like [codecov.io](https://codecov.io/) provide this feature

**diff-cover**

Projects like [diff-cover](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff_cover) highlight lines in your most recent change that are missing coverage.

> The `diff-cover` command line tool compares an XML coverage report with
>   the output of `git diff`. It then reports coverage information for lines
>   in the diff.